# <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to connect to api.twitter.com port 443: Connection timed out'

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I am working on a Codeigniter project where I used twitter api library to fetch twitter data. It was worked perfectly before I changed the server, but after changed server it produced bellow error. I don't know the problem.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to connect to api.twitter.com port 443: Connection timed out' in /my/project/path/myProject/application/ws/libraries/TwitterAPIExchange.php:297
Stack trace:
#0 /my/project/path/myProject/application/ws/controllers/alldata.php(247): TwitterAPIExchange-&gt;performRequest()
#1 /my/project/path/myProject/application/ws/controllers/alldata.php(40): Alldata-&gt;fetch_tweets('1', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Alldata-&gt;index()
#3 /my/project/path/myProject/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /my/project/path/myProject/index.php(188): require_once('/home/develnik/...')
#5 {main}
thrown in <b>/my/project/path/myProject/application/ws/libraries/TwitterAPIExchange.php</b> on line <b>297</b><br />
```

Comment: open port 443 on your new server, if it's on amazon make sure you defined the security groups correctly

Comment: @DanielKrom: It's already opened, and it's not on amazon

Comment: Well, then what did you change about the server - the server code, or the server machine - it's a bit unclear.

Comment: @St0fF  have changed server from Godday To Bluehost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your cPanel if port is opened or not, some times it shows opened but actually not. You can check it in your cPanel under health check and monitoring section for port details.